# How to send data from web socket server to client?

Tags: sockets, websocket, websocket-sharp

I started using `WebSocketSharp` to create a simple WebSocket Server. Everything works great with this simple code:

```
var service = new WebSocketCustomerImageService();

var serverSocket = new WebSocketServer("ws://localhost:2000");
serverSocket.AddWebSocketService<WebSocketCustomerImageService>("/customerImageService");
serverSocket.Start();
```

Service class:

```
    public class WebSocketCustomerImageService : WebSocketBehavior
    {
        protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Send("Hello from the other side!");
        }        
    }
```

This works great, the server responds when the client sends any message, but now, I want the server to send a message without the need of the client to send anything. The `Send()` method seems to only be available on the `WebSocketBehavior` class and I don't directly instanciate this `WebSocketCustomerImageService` class.

How can access the created instance to use the `Send()` method or what's the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok solved it using:

```
serverSocket.WebSocketServices["/customerImageService"].Sessions.Broadcast("My data");
```

This sends `"My data"` to all clients listening on `/customerImageService`